# How to create a Maven project with Hibernate and Struts

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, struts

How to create a Maven project with Hibernate and Struts 2.

I am hoping to use Eclipse as my IDE.

Comment: it's Struts, not Structs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could run the following and select project from the list

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

when you're done just change to the newly created project and run the following to have the eclipse project files created, then in eclipse file/import

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Answer (score 2):

- get the m2eclipse plugin, and optionally - m2eclipse-wtp
- create a new maven project (from the New dialog). You can also "mavenize" existing projects, from the right-click menu > Maven.
- right click the pom.xml and add hibernate and struts dependencies

Comment: how do i get the `m2eclipse plugin` ?

Comment: 1. google for m2eclipse or 2. open the eclipse marketplace and look for it

Comment: @Illep. Use m2e ( it supersedes m2eclipse ).  Here is the link -> http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/

Answer (score 2):

There are "Spring Template applications" in eclipse. Just start with one of them.
Use [STS](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) rather than plain old eclipse, just fewer headaches.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the command prompt.
2. Customize following command and type in command prompt.

   ```
   mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.init -DartifactId=TestMavenProject
   ```

Please refer following link for more info.

https://howisolvedproblems.blogspot.com/2018/02/how-to-start-maven-project-from-scratch.html